# OpenSSL error using Omniauth, specified ssl path but didn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl, omniauth

When my site get /auth/twitter, I got this:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed):
```

I modified the omniauth configuration for twitter:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :twitter, 'BLANKED', 'BLANKED',  {:client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_path => "/etc/ssl/certs/"}}}
end
```

No dice.

Checked the path, /etc/ssl/certs/ and it exists as far as I can tell.

I am using omniauth 0.2.6 and faraday 0.6.1.

Comment: do you have openssl and other related libs? can you update public root ssl certs?

Comment: I have access to my VPS so I can probably update public root ssl certs. Openssl is installed.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following lines to the file config/initializers/omniauth.rb helps!

```
    OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

But this config will not verify your SSL certificates. I did this a long time ago for one of my app in staging which didn't have SSL so beware!
Don't do this in production.

Comment: this helped me while authenticating facebook and twitter via omniauth and also when pulling contacts from gmail using omnicontacts

Comment: helped me too with facebook auth.

Comment: Terrible solution. Now none of your SSL certificates will be verified.

Comment: Just realized i forgot to mention about that along with the answer, this config will not verify your SSL certificates. I did this a long time ago for one of my app which didn't have SSL

Answer (score 0):

You are not the only one with this problem. It seems to be a known issue with the latest version of omniauth and faraday. Check the issue on github to stay up-to-date: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/404

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Twitter-specific, see:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/twitter-development-talk/THQegQjSScs

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/533